# How can I convert my json data to a string array and display the text?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

So I'm using the fetch api to get some data.
I have sucessfully managed to get the data and can display the response with console log. However, I want to actually use this data.
The api gives me "result", "id" and "total". I need help how can I convert this to a string array and actually use the information generated from the api.

I have tried messing around with JSON.Parse but I haven't really been able to convert the json data to a string array.

function addPost(e){
      e.preventDefault();

```
  let itemname = document.getElementById('itemname').value;
  let body = document.getElementById('body').value;

  fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/search/Standard', {
    method:'POST',

    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-type':'application/json'
    },
    body:JSON.stringify({"query": {"status": {"option": "online"}, "name":itemname, "stats": [{"type": "and", "filters": []}]},"sort": {"price": "asc"}})
  })
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));
}
```

Comment: *I haven't really been able to convert the json data*.... what about `JSON.parse()` doesnt work? And what does the response `data` look like? Do this `.then((data) => console.log(data));`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for->

```
  var item;

  fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/search/Standard', {
    method:'POST',

    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-type':'application/json'
    },
    body:JSON.stringify({"query": {"status": {"option": "online"}, "name":itemname, "stats": [{"type": "and", "filters": []}]},"sort": {"price": "asc"}})
  })
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => item = JSON.stringify(data));

JSON.parse(item).result
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but I get error:
VM34:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLFormElement.addPost (index.html:93)
addPost @ index.html:93
It seems like the parse doesn't actually get any data?